# Is there a way to execute an HTTP request with multiple headers with the same key in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, request, authorization

i'm facing a problem with my Node.js backend.
I have to call an API that sadly requires the Authorization header duplicated, one with a Basic token and one with a Bearer token.
Unfortunately a third party provides the api, therefore i have no control over it.
Also that API for some reason doesn't work if i concatenate the two values with a comma (Basic foo,Bearer bar), so sadly that is not a solution.

I'm able to do the request with curl in the terminal

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://service.com/test' --header 'Authorization: Basic token' --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"foo": "bar"}'
```

I have tried many different http request libraries but all of them, rightfully, use a dictionary to store headers, which does not accept a duplicated key.

Do you know any library that treats the headers differently, or any other workaround to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fire up netcat to see what a server would see:

```
nc -l -p 10000
```

Client code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function main() {
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:10000/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': [
                'Authorization: Basic token',
                'Authorization: Bearer token',
            ],
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
    });
}

main().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Netcat prints:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Authorization: Basic token
Authorization: Authorization: Bearer token
User-Agent: axios/1.2.0
Content-Length: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:10000
Connection: keep-alive

{"foo":"bar"}
```